# distribution function of random variable - negative infinity

Tags: stochastic-processes

This doubt is from the book Stochastic Processes by Ross..Chapter 1, subsection Random variables.

The distribution function F of the random variable X is defined for any
real number x by

F(x) = P{X$\leq$x} = P{X $\epsilon$ (-$\infty$,x]}

I have not understood why X $\epsilon$ (-$\infty$,x] and not [0,x]

How is X $\epsilon$ (-$\infty$,x] to be practically interpreted?
Request help understand

Comment: If you have some random numbers, they might as well be negative.

Comment: The expression at the bottom of the question is equivalent to $X\le x$

Comment: Ok...understood...in case x denotes event nos, then we take it from [0,x]?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a particular example. Suppose that a random variable $X$ is equal to $-1$ almost surely. What is the probability that the value of this random variable is less than or equal to some positive number $x$, i.e. $P(X\le x)$, where $x>0$? This probability is not equal to the probability $P(X\in[0,x])$, it is equal to the probability $P(X\in(-\infty,x])$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes Thank you,,,, I was taking x as to be events and not general random numbers... so could not figure out how events could be negative.

Comment: @SAK You're welcome! Yes, $X$ is a random variable and $F(x)$ denotes the probability of the event that the random variable takes value in the set $(-\infty,x]$, i.e. the probability of the event $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in(-\infty,x]\}$.